# Could not find rake-10.3.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound) on HTTPS push

Tags: ruby, git, rake, gitlab

Error Prompt：

```
Mac:symfony apple$ git push -u origin master
Counting objects: 3, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 209 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bundler-1.7.4/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `block in materialize': Could not find rake-10.3.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
remote:         from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bundler-1.7.4/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `map!'
remote:         from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bundler-1.7.4/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `materialize'
remote:         from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bundler-1.7.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:132:in `specs'
remote:         from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bundler-1.7.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:177:in `specs_for'
remote:         from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bundler-1.7.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:166:in `requested_specs'
remote:         from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bundler-1.7.4/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs'
remote:         from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bundler-1.7.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup'
remote:         from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bundler-1.7.4/lib/bundler.rb:121:in `setup'
remote:         from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bundler-1.7.4/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
remote:         from /usr/lib64/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
remote:         from /usr/lib64/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
```

**server system env:**

```
[root@proxyA gitlab]# bundle env|grep rake
rake (>= 0.8.7)
rake
rake (>= 0.8.7)
rake (10.3.2)

[root@proxyA gitlab]# bundle exec rake -V

rake, version 10.3.2

[root@proxyA gitlab]# rake -V
rake, version 10.3.2
```

ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22 revision 43784) [x86_64-linux]

Testing the server and client are on the same server

This error occurs when I submit data after installation gitlab, please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible duplicate of: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/8045, with fix proposed at: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/pull/8131 Go there an ping the fix to improve the probability it will get merged sooner.

I recommend that you always look at https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues first for bugs, and that you add what triggers the problem to question titles when possible (HTTPS push here) ;)